The difference between two description of affine Weyl groups
I have a question about the difference between two description of affine Weyl groups.
Let me write two descriptions of affine Weyl groups:

Let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}(A)$ be affine Lie algebras with $\{\mathfrak{h},\Pi=\{\alpha_0,\cdots ,\alpha_l\},\Pi^\vee=\{\alpha_0^\vee,\ldots,\alpha_\ell^\vee\} \}$ where $A=(a_{ij})_{0\le i,j\le l}$ and $\overset{0}{\mathfrak{g}}$ is a simple  finite-dimensional Lie algebra  whose Dynkin diagram $S(\overset{0}{A})$ is obtained from Dynkin diagram $S(A)$ by removing the $0$th vertex. 
The set $\overset{0}{Q}=\mathbb{Z}\overset{0}{\Delta}$  where $\mathbb{Z}\overset{0}{\Delta}$ is the root system of  $\overset{0}{\mathfrak{g}}$ and $\overset{0}{W}$ can be seen as  the Weyl group of $\overset{0}{\mathfrak{g}}$.

(1): In Chapter $6$ of Kac's book Infinite-Dimensional Lie Algebras, the author defines the Weyl group of $\mathfrak{g}$ $W=\langle s_0,s_1,\cdots,s_l \rangle $ where $s_i(\lambda)=\lambda-\langle \lambda ,\alpha _{i}^\vee\rangle \alpha _i$ for any $\lambda\in h^*$.
He proves $W=\overset{0}{W}\ltimes T$ where $T=\{t_\alpha\mid \alpha\in M \}$ , $M=\nu \left( \mathbb{Z}\left( \overset{0}{W}\cdot \theta ^{\lor} \right) \right) $ and $\nu:\mathfrak{h}\to \mathfrak{h}^*$ is defined by the nondegenerate symmetric bilinear $\mathbb{C}$-valued form $(.\mid .)$.
Here is a description of the lattice $M$:
\begin{aligned}
&M=\mathring{Q}\text{ if }A\text{ is symmetric or }r>a_0;\\
&M=\nu(\mathring{Q}^{\vee})\text{ otherwise.}
\end{aligned}
Through some discussions, the author gives an isomorphism from $W$ onto a group of affine transformations $W_{af}$ of $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{R}}^*=\langle \alpha_0,\cdots,\alpha_l\rangle $ over $\mathbb{R}$.
(2): In Chapter $4$ of James E. Humphreys's book Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups, give a Weyl group $W_1$, a root system $\varPhi$ and the set of corrots $\alpha^\vee=2\alpha /\left( \alpha ,\alpha \right)$. He define $s_{\alpha,k}(\lambda)=\lambda -\left( \left( \lambda ,\alpha \right) -k \right) \alpha ^{\lor}$ for each root $\alpha$  and each integer $k$.
He defines the affine Weyl group $W_a$ is generated by all affine reflections $s_{\alpha,k} $ where $\alpha\in \varPhi$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
He also proves that $W_a=W\ltimes L$ where $L$ is the coroot lattice.
Here are my questions:
In Kac's description $(W_{af}=\overset{0}{W}\ltimes T)$, here $T$ can be sometimes seen as the root lattice of $\overset{0}{\mathfrak{g}}$. So we can sometimes think the affine weyl group $W_{af}$ is the semidirect product of a weyl group of a simple Lie algebras and a root lattice.
But in  Humphreys's description $(W_a=W\ltimes L)$, then the affine weyl groups is the semidirect product of a weyl group and a root lattice.
I would like to know why these two descriptions are different (i.e. in (1) it is the root lattice and in (2) it it coroot lattice) and if these two descriptions coincide?
If not, when we mention affine Weyl groups of affine Lie algebras, Which one is needed ?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
